# Display Longtext Description Output

Tags: php, html, css, youtube

Hello how to display the content on the database correctly

> [center][youtube]vn9mMeWcgoM[/youtube] [/center]
>   [center]This is a test youtube post video [/center][center][img]http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-RgszeTgP4eA/Vck93de-LZI/AAAAAAAAaOQ/F0s-XK5Zh4c/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/samabawan_island_leyte_philippines.jpg[/img][/center]

That is the Output it should display the image and video

This is my display code

```
<?php echo nl2br($item['content']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you can do this by using [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

And this is a simple function i have written, i hope this helps you.

```
$text = "[center][youtube]vn9mMeWcgoM[/youtube] [/center] [center]This is a test youtube post video [/center][center][img]http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-RgszeTgP4eA/Vck93de-LZI/AAAAAAAAaOQ/F0s-XK5Zh4c/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/samabawan_island_leyte_philippines.jpg[/img][/center]";

function replace($string){
    $string = preg_replace("/\[center\](.*?)\[\/center]/", "<div align='center'>$1</div>", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/\[youtube\](.*?)\[\/youtube]/", "<iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1\"></iframe>", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img]/", "<img src='$1' />", $string);
    return $string;
}

echo replace($text);
```

For your code, call it like this, `echo nl2br(replace($item['content']));`

**EDITED**

Here is the way you can add more tags,
First read about the function [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

And read [Possible modifiers in regex patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for more informations.

Now you can add,

```
    $string = preg_replace("/\[url\](.*?)\[\/url]/", "<a href=\"$1\" >$1</a>", $string);
```

After last $string variable in my simple function.

This mean replace what inside URL tags with `<a href=\"$1\" >$1</a>`
And $1 is the URL, in most cases $1 is the element you want.

Comment: Its working now dude.. But my concerns is this will work also on a link,tables, Text color and etc.?

Comment: @ClintonCanarias Its a pleasure to hear that, All are the same way, you can edit the function as you wish, i edited the answer, Second if i helped you please click on (click to accept this answer) and welcome to the community.

Comment: Its already done by the thanks I use ckeditor it much easier compare to sceditor because the output is bbcode while ckeditor is html. By the way thank you very much

Comment: @ClintonCanarias You're welcome, Yeah there is a lot of free editors you can find, if my answer helped you, just click to accept this answer to make mark your question as solved.